# Xamarin.Forms Preview Screen Isn't Working

Tags: java, c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

In my Xamarin.Forms project the preview screen stopped responding after I edited my .xaml file. It is giving java.lang.NullPointerException error, but it doesn't show any errors in the errors section in Visual Studio 2019. My final .xaml file is below:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:map="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="x.MainPage">

    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2.1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="160" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label  Text="x" TextColor="DimGray" FontSize="35" Margin="5"/>
                    <SearchBar Text="x" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="5"/>
                    <Label Text="x" FontSize="Large" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="160" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general-9/500/add-512.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="0.5" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <Image Source="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general-9/500/add-512.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="0.5" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Image Source="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general-9/500/add-512.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="0.5" Grid.Column="2" />
                        <Image Source="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general-9/500/add-512.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="0.5" Grid.Column="3" />
                        <Image Source="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general-9/500/add-512.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="0.5" Grid.Column="4" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Label  Text="x" FontSize="Caption" Margin="5" TextColor="#000AFF" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <map:Map x:Name="Map" MapType="Street" HasZoomEnabled="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO !

After checking code , there is a property of `SearchBar` can cause this error .

Modify `IsEnabled="False"` to `IsEnabled="True"` , or if want `SearchBar` not shows can set `IsVisible="False"` .

Effect as follow :

[image]

In addition , you defined only one row in the first Grid , however used setted the second one :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="160" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0">
```

If changed to :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="160" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0">
```

Preview Screen will show as follow :

[image]

The same wrong setted is in fourth `Grid` , you can check that .